# How an ICO works

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20, ico

Well, I'm working on developing an NFT game. So far it's all right.
I have already created my ERC20 contract for currency. At that moment when I create the contract I created 5 separate portfolios, each portfolio will have 20%.

My question now is the following:
I realized that in order to add my currency to Pancake, I need to have liquidity, correct?
In this case I need to collect funds, and I found the ICO alternative. That said, I made a contract that will sell 20% of my tokens and whatever is generated I would put in Pancake.
And here that the question arises, for me to add liquidity I need to have 20% of my token, however, I have already allocated all the % to portfolios with different purposes, and how do I add liquidity when I don't have plus the tokens?

Or better, could you explain to me how I can do this? I've been researching a lot on the topic, I can't find anything that is "explanatory" enough on the way these questions work.